# Excel Formula for dragging data horizontally

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What would be a good formula to drag vertical dates into horizontal rows? For example if you drag the selected cell to the right it should pull up the vertical dates.

[image]

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With INDEX:

```
=INDEX($F:$F,COLUMN(A1)+3)
```

With TRANSPOSE if one has Office 365 Excel:

```
=TRANPOSE($F$4:$F$6)
```

And it will spill to the right.

Comment: Thank you Scott, the "Transpose" formula works well.